# How to get code line by line in jscodeshift

Tags: javascript, jscodeshift

I am very new to jscodeshift. Is it possible to get code line by line.

```
export default function transformer(file, api) {
  const j = api.jscodeshift;


  return j(file.source).forEach(p => {
    p.value.program.body.forEach(p => {
        console.log(p)
    });

  }).toSource();
}
```

But the problem with this approach is such that i can't apply transformations to the resultant obtained in the variable `p`. For example. For the input below

```
    var a = "hello";
    var b = "stackoverflow";
    var c = a + b;
```

I need to transform the content line by line. is it possible to apply transformation line by line in jscodeshift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.get().node.program.body` and loop over that:
http://astexplorer.net/#/gist/fea38e8a6837d227fd02cb1297824280/be3b1fb941ee3e6dfbe4eea86610a3ad48e2b511

This:

```
const transformer = (file, api) => {
    const j = api.jscodeshift;
    const root = j(file.source);

    root.get().node.program.body.map((line) => {
        line.kind = "const";
    });
    return root.toSource();
};
export default transformer;
```

Transforms:

```
var a = "hello";
var b = "stackoverflow";
var c = a + b;
```

To:

```
const a = "hello";
const b = "stackoverflow";
const c = a + b;
```

You didn't ask for an exact transformation, so I just provided an example that morphed each line.

But you should note that the advantage of an Abstract Syntax Tree is that you do *not* need to go line by line. If you are able to provide what transformation you are looking for, it is likely that the community could provide you with a better solution than looping line by line.

Comment: I want to transform such that if i find a string at a line i need to add a comment(`This should not be translated`) at the end of the line if the above comment is not present.

Comment: seems like nobody knows jscodeshiift, it is so hard that even stackoverflow answers are missing.